# Firebase Unity UIHandler namespace mismatch

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I am getting two repeat error messages from the Unity console in my Firebase authorization demo:

Assets\Firebase\Sample\Auth\LoginIHandler.cs(576,9): error CS0103: The name 'auth' does not exist in the current context

The other repeat message is:
Assets\Firebase\Sample\Auth\LoginIHandler.cs(475,48): error CS1061: 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no accessible extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I remove:
  using UnityEngine.UI;

the messages disappear and I get:
Assets\Firebase\Sample\Auth\LoginIHandler.cs(35,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Text' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have created variables in the UIHandler:
     public Text emailText;
     public Text passwordText;

I have downloaded the latest versions of the samples from the GitHub quickstart repo
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/database/testapp

And followed along with the deletions to the UIHandler in this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjWHVye4kxo&t=698s

Answer (score 0):

You likely didn't follow the instructions in the readme. The Firebase sample apps don't ship with the SDK for various practical and legacy reasons.

For all of the test apps, you will need to [integrate the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add-sdks). You can check which is the latest [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity), I still typically download the unitypkg files and integrate them that way but you can use the Unity Package Manager (all covered in that first link).

Make sure that you install the packages in the dotnet4 folder. If you're using a recent version of Unity, it's likely the only valid SDK (you'll get different issues around Task if you choose dotnet3). If you're using an early 2018 release or older, you'll have to figure out which scripting runtime you're using.

If you are using the [Database quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/database/testapp), you will need to follow the instructions to make your database publicly accessible and you'll have to change your database URL.

If you are actually using the [Auth quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/auth/testapp), you will need to upload your SHA1 fingerprint and enable the auth providers you want to test.

I know it stinks to have to do this. Most of the issue is that there's not a way currently to completely configure a new project via the command line with all the settings that are needed. There's also concerns about Unity versions supported, note that the quickstart *does* list its unity version as 5.6 so there would have to be special logic to switch it over to the dotnet3 SDK for those Unity editors. Not impossible, but it would make the sample harder to understand if you had to sift through all this one-off build logic.

Also, you shouldn't need to perform those deletions in the video. It's likely that the person had an older version of the Firebase SDK they were integrating with a newer version of the quickstarts.

I hope this helps!

--Patrick